# Ionize CMS - module with second database

Tags: database, module, frameworks, content-management-system

I am new in the **Ionize CMS** world and I need your help. Is there a possibility to make a module to work with a second database? The idea is to create two types of website:

- one as **database management** (with own database **db1**) where content is added/modified and deleted. The database of this website will serve content for the second kind of  website
- the second type (with own database **db2**) , will display contents from database of first website db1 (based on a specific configuration, doesn't matter). For this website I want to make a module with the main purpose to get data from **db1**

Based on the documentation I saw how can access an module the parent database (CMS database db2) but not now to use tables from other database (e.g. db1)

This kind of website will installed on same or different hosting.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Ionize is a CMS based on CodeIgniter you could use more database conections.
To do what you need on second type of website, you should to define database configurations in `\application\config\database.php`

**Sample config:**

```
$db['db1']['hostname'] = '';
$db['db1']['username'] = '';
$db['db1']['password'] = '';
$db['db1']['database'] = '';
$db['db1']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['db1']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['db1']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['db1']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['db1']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['db1']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['db1']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['db1']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['db1']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_unicode_ci';

$db['db2']['hostname'] = '';
$db['db2']['username'] = '';
$db['db2']['password'] = '';
$db['db2']['database'] = '';
$db['db2']['dbdriver'] = 'mysqli';
$db['db2']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['db2']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['db2']['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$db['db2']['db_debug'] = FALSE;
$db['db2']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['db2']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['db2']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['db2']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_unicode_ci';
```

where **db1**  will be the default database, used by Ionizem and **db2** will be the database from **website type 1**.
After this, you could make queries on **db2** using something like this:

```
$this->remote_db = $this->load->database('db2', TRUE);
$query = $this->remote_db ->get('table_from_website_1');
```

With this aproach don't use persistent connection ( `['pconnect'] = FALSE;`)

For me, this configuration works like a charm